# Windows Phone 8 Check if location is turned on/off?

Tags: windows-phone-8, location

I want to check if the location service is turned on or off, so I can inform the user that he needs to turn it on in order to see his location on the map. Also want to check if airplane mode is on/off and if WiFi is turned on/off. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For location:

```cs
Geolocator locator = new Geolocator();
if (locator.LocationStatus == PositionStatus.Disabled)
{
    // Location is turned off
}
```

For network stuff, see [`DeviceNetworkInformation` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). E.g.

```cs
bool isWifiOn = DeviceNetworkInformation.IsWiFiEnabled;
```

See also: [How to detect network changes for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487166%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)